# Downloading file with Japanese characters in file name does not appear properly in IE

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to download a file which contains Japanese characters on file name, but after downloading it shows some unwanted/unrecognized characters instead of corresponding Japanese characters like

```
å„ªå…ˆãƒ‡ãƒ¼ã‚¿â‘ _20140411_2-J
```

Could anyone tell me how to convert the file name?

```
if docs.count()==1:

    resp = HttpResponse(docs[0].completed_document,mimetype=mimetypes.guess_type(docs[0].filename())[0])
    resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % docs[0].filename()
```

Comment: Have you tried add decode？like: resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % docs[0].filename().decode("utf8")

Comment: I tried that one but i got an error like                         'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 21-26: ordinal not in range(128), HTTP response headers must be in US-ASCII format